# Empty Values is returning to an array using express

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm Still learning with express so I'm new, Alright so I'm trying to send data from the form that I have created to and array, but unfortunately it's returning an empty value to the array.
therefor the values are showing in the console "consoe.log".

**HTML FORM PAGE CODE**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>New Movie</h1>
                <form action="/movies" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Movie Title" name="title">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Movie Img" name="image">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Movie Date" name="date">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Movie Time" name="time">
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**HTML and EJS**

```
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <% for (let movie of moviesList) { %>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="co-12">
                        <%= movie.movieImg %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <%= movie.movieTitle %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <%= movie.movieDate %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <%= movie.movieTime %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% } %>
        </div>
        <a href="/movies/new">New Movie</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

**App.js File**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const ip = require("ip");
const path = require('path');
const port = 8800;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// ================ DB ================ //

const moviesList = [
    {
        movieTitle:'Movie 1',
        movieImg: 'Movie Image Link',
        movieDate: '2021',
        movieTime: '100 min'
    },
    {
        movieTitle:'Movie 2',
        movieImg: 'Movie Image Link',
        movieDate: '2021',
        movieTime: '100 min'
    },
    {
        movieTitle:'Movie 3',
        movieImg: 'Movie Image Link',
        movieDate: '2021',
        movieTime: '100 min'
    },
    {
        movieTitle:'Movie 4',
        movieImg: 'Movie Image Link',
        movieDate: '2021',
        movieTime: '100 min'
    }
]

// ================ DB ================ //

// ================ Content ================ //
app.get("/movies", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("movies", { moviesList })
})
app.get("/movies/new", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("new-movie")
})
app.post("/movies", (req, res) => {
    const { title, date } = req.body;
    moviesList.push( {title, date})
    console.log(req.body)
    res.redirect("/movies")
})
// ================ Content End ================ //


app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Visit: http://localhost:${port}, as for the other devices Visit: http://${ip.address()}:${port}`)
})
```

this is the code that I'm working on right now..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem is fixed, so I re-read the code multiple time and carefully and the issue was from the form name attribute value and and json array keys or title inside the (app.post).
And below is my edited and updated code.

**HTML FORM PAGE CODE**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>New Movie</h1>
                <form action="/movies" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Movie Img" name="movieImg">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Movie Title" name="movieTitle">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Movie Date" name="movieDate">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Movie Time" name="movieTime">
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**App.js File**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const ip = require("ip");
const path = require('path');
const port = 8800;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// ================ DB ================ //

const moviesList = [
    {
        movieTitle:'Movie 1',
        movieImg: 'Movie Image Link',
        movieDate: '2021',
        movieTime: '100 min'
    },
    {
        movieTitle:'Movie 2',
        movieImg: 'Movie Image Link',
        movieDate: '2021',
        movieTime: '100 min'
    },
    {
        movieTitle:'Movie 3',
        movieImg: 'Movie Image Link',
        movieDate: '2021',
        movieTime: '100 min'
    },
    {
        movieTitle:'Movie 4',
        movieImg: 'Movie Image Link',
        movieDate: '2021',
        movieTime: '100 min'
    }
]

// ================ DB ================ //

// ================ Content ================ //
app.get("/movies", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("movies", { moviesList })
})
app.get("/movies/new", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("new-movie")

})
app.post("/movies", (req, res) => {
    const { movieTitle, movieImg, movieDate, movieTime } = req.body;
    moviesList.push({movieTitle, movieImg, movieDate, movieTime})
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(moviesList)
    res.redirect("/movies")
})
// ================ Content End ================ //


app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Visit: http://localhost:${port}, as for the other devices Visit: http://${ip.address()}:${port}`)
})
```